# Crossprod issue in R

Tags: r, cross-product

I recently came up with an issue where cross prod seems to behave strangely.

```
> is.symmetric.matrix(crossprod(M1))
[1] TRUE
> is.symmetric.matrix(crossprod(M1,M1))
[1] FALSE

> dput(M1)
```

> structure(c(0.662345679012346, -0.0537037037037037,
>   -0.0537037037037037, 
>   -0.0537037037037037, -0.0537037037037037, -0.0537037037037037, 
>   -0.0537037037037037, -0.0537037037037037, -0.0555533333333333, 
>   -0.0555533333333333, -0.0555533333333333, -0.0555533333333333, 
>   -0.0555533333333333, -0.0555533333333333, -0.0555533333333333, 
>   -0.0555533333333333, -0.082849523255722, 0.209560558823297, 0.794380722981334, 
>   0.794380722981334, -0.082849523255722, 0.209560558823297, -0.082849523255722, 
>   -0.082849523255722, -0.0333333333333333, 0.05, -0.0333333333333333, 
>   0.133333333333333, -0.0333333333333333, -0.0333333333333333, 
>   -0.0333333333333333, 0.05, 0.00722926923433098, 1.91575634709772, 
>   0.00722926923433098, -0.513278115637501, -0.686780577261445, 
>   -0.339775654013557, -0.686780577261445, -0.686780577261445, 0.138472834067548, 
>   -0.0585636096649313, 0.0727940194900547, -0.124242424242424, 
>   0.0727940194900547, 0.00711520491256175, -0.124242424242424, 
>   -0.124242424242424, -0.665219916932936, -1.33980912847056, -0.271709543535988, 
>   0.0655850622328247, -2.29547717814886, -2.29547717814886, -1.73331950186751, 
>   1.58341078819248, -0.0829545454545454, -0.0829545454545454, -0.0829545454545454, 
>   -0.0829545454545454, 0.0725852272727273, -0.0829545454545454, 
>   -0.0829545454545454, -0.0829545454545454, -0.865647461169836, 
>   -1.73543677622087, 4.41521623735429, -1.48692554334914, -0.555008420080178, 
>   -4.46906033780982, -3.72352663919465, 2.92414884012395, -0.00937499999999999, 
>   -0.00937499999999999, -0.00937499999999999, 0.69375, -0.15, -0.00937499999999999, 
>   -0.15, -0.15, -8.09053494329047, -6.04111906819099, 0.852370693507286, 
>   0.666060159407333, -3.24646105669169, -2.31490838619192, -10.13995081839, 
>   -3.24646105669169), .Dim = c(8L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
>       NULL))

Anyone faced such an issue before. I have dput the output to reproduce this issue. It fails only for few type of matrix. Though there are many alternatives , I would like to know if i am missing anything here while executing crossprod(X,X) rather than crossprod(X)

> $version.string [1] "R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)"

Comment: Everything work for me in R3.4.1 and is `TRUE`. `identical(crossprod(M1, M1), crossprod(M1))`, 
`isSymmetric.matrix(crossprod(M1))`, 
`isSymmetric.matrix(crossprod(M1, M1))`.

Comment: On my R 3.4.1 `is.symmetric.matrix(crossprod(M1,M1))` gives `TRUE`

Comment: for same M1 that i have dput?

Comment: Yes. For the same M1

Comment: I get TRUE on both with R 3.4.2 patched.